# Add padding to UILabel with NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel

I want to add some padding to a highlighted UILabel (see screenshot). 
[image]

I have tried subclassing the UILabel like so without succes:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 0, 0); //customize padding here
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.edgeInsets)];
}
```

Current function to create the label:

```
    paddingLabel  *viewTitleLabel = [[paddingLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

    NSMutableAttributedString *s =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:ticketcode];

    [s addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
              value:[UIColor blackColor]
              range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];


    viewTitleLabel.attributedText = s;
```

Comment: Add padding to label? You mean you need some space in front of the image?

Comment: More like insets to all four sides

Answer (score 0):

Swift solution for left indentation:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 10
paragraphStyle.headIndent = 10
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
```